# Delete a letter

Tags: prolog

i create something but it doesn't worked.The exercise was telling to delete a letter.Example ([c,o,m,k,p,u,t,e,r]) the k must be eliminated.

```
den([c,o,m,p,u,t,e,r]).
den([n,e,t,w,o,r,k]).
den([p,r,o,g,r,a,m]). 

% (c) delete(X,L1,L2):-
%       append(A,[X,T],L1),
%       append(A,T,L2).

%   <------------------ L -------------------->
%   +-----------------------------------------+
%   |<-> A <-> | X | <-> B <-> | Y | <-> C <->|
%   +-----------------------------------------+
%   <--------- F --------->
%   +-------------------------------------+
%   |<-> A <-> | <-> B <-> | Y | <-> C <->|
%   +-------------------------------------+
%   <-------------- CL --------------->
%   +---------------------------------+
%   |<-> A <-> | <-> B <-> | <-> C <->|
%   +---------------------------------+

delete_extra(Word, CorrectWord) :-
    append(Begin, [Letter1|Ypoloipo], Word),
    append(Middle, [Letter2|End], Ypoloipo),
    word(CorrectWord),
    append(Begin, YpoloipoCW, CorrectWord),
    append(Middle, End, YpoloipoCW),
    Letter1 \= Letter2.
```

Comment: with the appends it is as simple as `append(Begin, [Letter | Rest], Word), append(Begin, Rest, CorrectWord)`. The first append potentially picks every letter in the `Word`, so you just glue together the two parts that are left. Either of which can be empty, `[]`. these two appends together *are* equivalent to `select(Letter, Word, CorrectWord)` (except for the latter not defining the `Begin` and `Rest` logical variables, of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be as simple as:

```
delete_extra(Word, CorrectWord) :-
    select(_, Word, CorrectWord),
    den(CorrectWord).
```

Sample call:

```
?- delete_extra([c,o,m,k,p,u,t,e,r], CorrectWord).
CorrectWord = [c, o, m, p, u, t, e, r] ;
false.
```

The `select/3` predicate is a de facto standard library predicate over lists that non-deterministically selects an element from a list, returning it and the rest of the list.

Comment: Not sure why you were assuming that the first letter was always correct but the idea of looking for a letter somewhere in the word that would be wrong was going in the right direction.

Comment: this answer it can be used in any case?example it can be used for delete to same letters if there was a letter more computerm.There are to m.So can it be used ?

Comment: It can be used when there is a **single** extra letter in the word, no matter its position.

Comment: @q.a to clarify, yes, even though there are two `m`s in `computerm`, you can use `select/3` to remove *either one* of them. the second removal, of the last `m`, leads to the correct word.